# Combinations of alphabet in Char array

Tags: java

I have a char array of A, B, C and I want to print the output as:

`A,B,C,AB,AC,BC,ABC`

Any suggestions will be appreciated...

```
public class CharArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char alpha[] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
        for(char s : alpha) {
                    //what to do now
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want *permutations* or all *combinations*?

Comment: I want all combinations not the permutations.. So Suppose if the Char array is `A, B, C` then the output should be like this `A,B,C,AB,AC,BC,ABC` but not BA, CA, CB and CBA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This prints *combinations*, as in your example, not *permutations*, as in the title of the question.

```
char alpha[] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
for (int m = 1 ; m != 1<<alpha.length ; m++) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != alpha.length ; i++) {
        if ((m & (1<<i)) != 0) {
            System.out.print(alpha[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Could we have some notes on how/why this works, or a reference please?

Comment: Oh I get it! m goes from 1 to (1 << n) - 1 (7 in this case) thus enumerating 001b, 010b, 011b, ... 111b which is all combinations of three elements. The inner loop just tests each bit and prints if it is a 1. Sill very nice. :)

Comment: @Dasblikenlight awesome solution mate....I was searching for this algo from past 10 hrs and atlast got it over here...If you dont mind can you please explain the solution?

Comment: @Patton when you iterate over numbers from 0 to `1<<n` (which is `2<<n`) the numbers go through all possible combinations of zeros and ones, and then you test its bits by masking with `2^0`, `2^1`, `2^2`, ..., `2^(n-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is in guava (an open source java library by google).

Sets (a set utilities class)

```
/**   Returns the set of all possible subsets of set. For example, powerSet(ImmutableSet.of(1, 2)) returns the set {{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}}... */
        public static <E> Set<Set<E>> powerSet(Set<E> set)
```

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#powerSet(java.util.Set)